# Display Error Page if Incorrect Route Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a route: /register

I wanna show user an error page which is like: 404 Page not found or redirect. How to do it in Laravel 4.2 route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily throw errors using:

```
App::abort(404);
```

If you need a custom 404 page, you'll just have to create a view for that and define it like this:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

If you want to do redirects:

```
return Redirect::to('/');
```

Sources:

- http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#http-exceptions
- http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add this code in your routes.php file.

```
App::missing(function($exception) {
    return Response::view('404', array(), 404);
});
```

During laravel installation a default 404 page is also shipped with it (Check in your views folder) else create a file in the views folder with the name `404.blade.php`

Hope this is helpful.